Find the relation between $a\neq0$, $b$, $c$, so that the domain and range of $f(x)=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ are the same
I am a secondary school student. Today, I faced a difficult problem in my exam: (the sentences are translated from Chinese)

Suppose there is a function $f(x)=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$ $(a\neq0)$, if the domain and the range of the function are same, find the relation between $a$, $b$ and $c$.

I've tried to divide the problem into three situations:

$a=0,b=0$
$a=0,b≠0$
$a≠0$

When I thought of the 1 and 2 situation, it seems that the 1 should be a point, and the 2 should be a line. How should I keep solving the problem? I can't get any relations in the 1 and 2 situation.
And, since the domain and range of $x$ and $y$ are same, then should I think about the possibility if $x<0$?
My question may be silly, but I hope that you can give me a hand.
Thanks.

Hint: Show that 1/ The origin is a point on the function, so $ c = 0$. 2/ $ a < 0$. 3/ $b>0 $ 4/ Find a relationship between $b$ and $a$. In particular, what can you say about $f(b/2)$?

Whilst this question can be solved by knocking around some algebra, it is probably easier to visualize (at a secondary-school level, at any rate) if considered graphically.  Rather than considering the function given, instead consider the curve
$y^2=ax^2+bx+c$
(only the parts of the curve with $y\ge0$ should be considered)
The problem then reduces to asking the question: what is the relationship between $a$, $b$ and $c$ for this curve to have the same $x$ and $y$ values.  (Note that this does not necessarily mean the curve is symmetric, but symmetry is a good starting point).
How far you get with this rather depends upon how much coordinate geometry you have done.  The shape of the curve depends largley upon the coefficient $a$: if it is negative, an ellipse; if it is positive, a hyperbola; if it is zero, a parabola.  We can rule out the parabola of course (but consider why).  What about the hyperbola?
Graphing this on Geogebra or Desmos (for example) with sliders might give you a little more insight, and then you should have a good idea how to apply the algebra and to solve it.

Thanks for your answer. However, I still wonder a question: since the domain and range of x and y are same, then should I think about the possibility if $x<0$?

So the possibility of values $x$ less that zero indeed need to be rejected, but $x=0$ must be in the domain. Half an ellipse passing through the origin perhaps?
